# Rails 5 timestamps not working for has_many through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

[ **TLDR:** Check your fixtures! (see answer below) ]

`gem 'rails', '5.2.3'`

I have two models, People and Puppies that are in a has_many "through" relationship. The join model is Companion.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :companions, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
    has_many :puppies, through: :companions

class Puppy < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :companions
    has_many :people, through: :companions

class Companion < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'people_puppies' #is the table name messing things up?
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :puppy
    default_scope { order(created_at: :asc) }
```

My problem is that `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps are not working on the Companion model. When I try to assign a new relationship between two records...

```
    @person.puppies << some_puppy
    # or
    @person.companions << some_puppy
    # or
    Companion.create!(puppy: some_puppy, person: @person)
```

...I get an DB constraint violation message:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: people_puppies.created_at: INSERT INTO "people_puppies" ("person_id", "puppy_id") VALUES (1052040621, 904095534)
```

Why isn't Rails adding the timestamps?

Here's the schema:

```
  create_table "people_puppies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "person_id", null: false
    t.integer "puppy_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["person_id", "puppy_id"], name: "index_people_puppies_on_person_id_and_puppy_id"
    t.index ["puppy_id", "person_id"], name: "index_people_puppies_on_puppy_id_and_person_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

WOOPS!

The DB constraint violation wasn't actually coming from `<<` or my test code at all. I had associations in my fixtures that were leftover from before I converted from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many through:`

Ex:

```
some_person:
  email: foo@gmail.com
  puppies:
     - some_puppy
```

^ THIS is what was causing the DB error before my test code even started. :-/

My original question was based on incorrect assumptions, but this seems like an easy mistake to make if you refactor from HABTM to `has_many through` (and you have preexisting fixtures). So even though it's embarrassing, I will leave this question in case it helps someone in the future.